# Importing single MySQL .sql file for ENTIRE Database | No Database Selected Error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I know it's probably not the correct way to do it, but I exported my entire database to a file called localhost.sql. I don't know how to import this to my new database, because it asks for a target database to put it in, but I don't have one, I need it to import the entire database, not to a table. Or at least that's how I understand it.

When I go to PhpMyAdmin and go to import and choose that file, then click Go, it gives this error...

## Error:

> SQL query
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pinnums`
> (`pin` varchar(5) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
>
> 1046 - No database selected

Yes it's pretty self-explanitory, but hours of looking at forums and trying stuff that dosn't make sence/work...I don't know...

*I don't think I can show my database file as it contains sensitive info.*

Most of my website runs off of these databases that I can't access, so I need them or all of my work is done for. :( Any thoughts help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay! I had a small hypothesis that the .sql file was text-editor-readable, and I was right, so I manually recreated all of my databases and filled them using the pre-made code in the .sql backup file. The reason for the error, is because which database the info should go in wasn't commented out for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create a new database in the target database server and then import the .sql file to that database.

```
`#mysql> create database <newdatabasename>;`
#shell> mysql -u<user> -p  <newdatabasename>  < localhost.sql
```

Comment: Uh, will that make all of my databases appear in the main list, or put them into a table?

Comment: this will restore all the tables of 1 database instance which is taken backup as localhost.sql. Can you paste the mysqldump command which was used to take backup.

Comment: I looked inside the file and I was all of the data from all the tables...and I didn't use mysqldump to make the .sql file...